# Layout puzzle: align to Left AND Right plus a Centered box All connected with a Line

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, alignment, positioning

I am trying to solve this layout puzzle but am stuck in how to get it as elegant, clean and timeless.

Given:

- a horizontal line of 1 pixel height stretching inside the container its in
- a vertically as well as horizontally centered box over this line
- a left aligned textbox
- and a right aligned text box

What I have tried, is painstakingly increment the percentages until I reached some kind of a middle... warning, the following code is very graphical and ugly!

CSS

```
author{color: grey}
box{float: left;
     background: blue;
     margin: 0 0 0 46.4%;
     ...
     /* bad coding feel embarrassed showing this */
}
time{color: grey}
```

HTML (flexible and can be changed)

```
<author></author>
<box><img src=""/></box>
<time></time>
```

I first thought this might be solved in flexbox, using `justify-content: space-between` however, I cannot figure out how to make the line appear there. So I am open for any suggestions whether it's the good old positioning/float or with flexbox. Maybe it would be nice to try to solve it both ways and see which one is the most elegant?

[image]

Comment: Is there a given markup?

Comment: Thanks Matthias I will provide the markup now (and update my question)! one moment

Comment: This fiddle may helps to you http://jsfiddle.net/wSd32/641/

Comment: Thanks @Znaneswar beautiful elegant answer! please put the jsFiddle as an Answer not as comment, sothat I can upvote it!

Comment: added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish that, where you use `justify-content: space-between` to align the `author`/`box`/`date` and an absolute positioned pseudo element to draw the line

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 50%; height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}
#wrapper > * {
  position: relative;            /*  instead of 'z-index: -1' on the pseudo so
                                     the line stays below the items  */
}

#author {}

#date {}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="author">
    Author
  </div>
  <div id="box">
  
  </div>
  <div id="date">
    Date
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

The `#wrapper > *` rule can in this case be replaced with setting `position: relative` on the `box`, which I recommend in favor of giving it a `z-index`.

---

Updated based on a 2nd comment

As you have issues with the combo Flexbox/script, here is one version without, with the same markup and an almost as short CSS

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 50%; height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}

#author {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#box { 
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="author">
    Author
  </div>
  <div id="box">
  
  </div>
  <div id="date">
    Date
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome @LGSon thanks! beautiful! One question: why not use `#box {z-index:2}`  ? What does the `#wrapper > * {position: relative}` do that the x-index cant? I see that z-index:2 on the #box works the same way, right? Thanks!

Comment: @Sam In this case the outcome is the same using `z-index`, though I prefer not use it if not needed, and since the pseudo has a position, also the `box` need one, to stay on top. The `wrapper > *` takes all above, but it would be enough with adding `position: relative` to the `box`

Comment: @Sam May I ask what's reason to undo the accept of my answer?

Comment: @Sam No offence taken, though got surprised since you yourself spoke about a Flexbox solution and no where mention that you actually prefer a non Flexbox based on your script issue. If that would been provided in the original question, you'd got another answer. I will provide a non Flexbox version.

Comment: I wanted to update my comment but you already answered. No problem mate I still believe your answer is the most elegant (just look at the amount of html code: brilliant) My acception is now permament ;) I really hope someday they fix the issues with flexbox slowing down javascript but that is off topic for the solutions provided here and you are right I do want flexbox, just must live with the side effects for now...

Comment: @Sam Added a 2nd sample for you :)

Comment: Awesome update! Very complete answer! Pity I cannot give it another upvote but I will try out your second take as well and see how that goes! Thanks again buddy! And indeed almost as short as the first one which is very nice.

Comment: PS #author, and #date can be combined into one selector:  `#author, #date{}` making it yet even shorter!

Comment: @Sam For 2 of the props. only, and still take more lines than what is :) ... well you can save 1 line ;)

Comment: Oops my mistake, it cant be i can see the difference now :)  `Left: 0` vs `Right: 0`  essential difference there :)

Comment: LGSon, may I draw your attention to this follow up question? :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427680/

Comment: @Sam I took a quick peek...and posted an answer

Comment: Thanks very much! I will take a look ( I also updated my question with the sprite, I hope you saw/see the updated version with the sprite) both versions of jsfiddle demo's were updated too accordingly to show the actual real world problem.

Comment: @Sam Had a second look, delete my answer and upvoted _G-Cyr's_, as that is the best for sprite's

Comment: Allright mate thank you very much again! I will dive into it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the below snippet provides a framework to do what you want to do. This uses flex boxes to hold three columns of divs (the left, the right, and the square). By setting the width of the square, the other two elements in the flex will fill the space. Left and right align settings are set in paragraph elements within divs.

This is by no means a very tidy solution, but does show how it can be done.

```css
.column {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}

.square {
  display: inline;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto 0;
  background: blue;
}

.top {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid black 2px;
}

.bottom {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.left-text {
  text-align: left;
}

.right-text {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="column left">
    <div class="top left">
      <p class="left-text">
        Author
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom left">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="square">

  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <div class="top right">
      <p class="right-text">
        Month Year
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom right">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @jon1467 I like it its very very **customizable**! Thus +1 upvoted thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Sam, that's what I was going for. It's always good to be able to come back to it in 2 years and still be able to understand it :p

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSd32/641/)

```css
#line{background: #000; height:1px; margin-top:40px;}
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    width:33.33333%;
    
}
.aligncenter {
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width:33.33333%;
}
.alignright {
    float: left;
    text-align:right;
    width:33.33333%;
    
}
.box{background:blue;margin:auto;width:40px;height:40px;display:block;margin-top:-20px;}
```

```html
<div id="line">
<p class="alignleft">Author</p>
<div class="aligncenter"><div class="box">
</div></div>
<p class="alignright">month/year</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```