# How to set 1px border and 1px outline for ENLARGED blown-up background sprite?

Tags: css, layout, background-image, sprite

I want to give my css-enlarged icon **sprite** a little white space followed by a 1px thin outline, like so:

[image]

Now I have tried these demos, with same elegant html and only varying CSS (with some help from standing on the shoulders of other talented giants in the community here):

[JS Fiddle Demo1](https://jsfiddle.net/effb5849/)
[JS Fiddle Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/q7nqkcu8/)

```
{
border: 1px solid white;
outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

However, in both approaches, as you can see, both border (which acts as a spacer here) and outline are much fatter than the 1px that I want. The challenge here is that I am using a huge background with coordinations as a sprite so there will be `background-position: 0 -3048;` for example.

If I try to set the border/outline in a parent div of the icon, then the entire layout falls apart!

And if I try `background-size: contain` then the entire sprite background gets crushed into a tiny icon size.

How can I achieve the thin 1px outline as shown in the image above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size` would be the best option, `flex` *would also be usefull here*.

You only have to update the `background-position`

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  margin:1.2em;
  align-items:center;
}
span {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: solid red 1px;
  margin:0 0 auto;
  height:25px;/* =============== half ico's height */
}
.line [class] {
  flex: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px gray;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/appdirect-assets/Blog%20Images/Content/2011/SVG-icons.png);
  background-size: 1100% 800%;/* 11x8*/
  background-position: 0px 1%;
}
span:last-of-type {
  text-align: right;
}
.line .ico2 {
  background-position:9.5% 15%;
}
.line .ico3 {
  background-position:20% 14.85%;
}
.bigger [class]{
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  margin-left:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span>text on left</span>
  <span class="ico1"></span>
  <span>text on right</span>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <span>text on left</span>
  <span class="ico2"></span>
  <span>text on right</span>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <span>text on left</span>
  <span class="ico3"></span>
  <span>text on right</span></div>
<div class="line bigger">
background-size rescales automaticly 
  <span class="ico1"></span>
  <span class="ico2"></span>
  <span class="ico3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer solves my layout puzzle: awesome new techniques that I did not know about and now can try learning! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have a `transform: scale` on the same element you are applying your border to.

Borders are applied before transforms, so the border gets scaled too.

The solution is to put your border on a parent element of the icon, and apply scale to the child element.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my updated question! I have clarified the problem and now the actual challenge and the real problem is more apparent. Please examine these two demos with your suggestion not working in a icon sprite:  https://jsfiddle.net/effb5849/  and https://jsfiddle.net/q7nqkcu8/    I thought I make the question simple by leaving out the sprite stuff but I cant, it makes the difference between a working icon and a broken icon so I decided to make my demo more complicated by approaching the reali life puzzle more precisely.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you use scale elements you'll never get a 1px line:

```
-ms-transform: scale(3); 
-o-transform: scale(3); 
-webkit-transform: scale(3); 
transform: scale(3);
```